# -moz-linear-gradient - what is the alternative for webkit

Tags: css

```
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( 270deg, rgba( 55, 55, 55, 0 ), rgba( 55, 55, 55, .1 ) ), -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(top left 45deg, rgba(255,255,255,.008), rgba(255,255,255,.008) 15px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 15px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 30px);
```

I would like to know if there's any alternative for this nice effect, for webkit browsers as well. The effect is working nicely in ff but not in chrome nor safari!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the pattern that's making, it looks like you could use the `-webkit-background-size` property? To demonstrate:

```
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(blue), to(white));
    -webkit-background-size: 60px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: `-webkit-gradient()` only works in older versions of Webkit. They changed it with the last major release to `-webkit-linear-gradient()` format as per W3C draft updates.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's pretty similar. Details at http://www.webkit.org/blog/1424/css3-gradients/

Comment: i fail on setting 270deg - i am not sure